# I am very new to Scala / SBT. Is there a test program I use to see I set everything up correctly?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to get into Scala / sbt to test things.  I am just using notepad++ and command line, no IDE.

Is there a "hello world" for tests program?  I was following the sbt website example for hello world which is this:

```
object Hi {
   def main(args: Array[String]) = println("Hi!")
}
```

Does anyone have a simple example test than I can run using SBT?  I have my directories setup correctly but am still getting the hang of using SBT for basic tests and a simple example would help greatly.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I had tried using the intellij idea IDE at first with scala / sbt and scalatest to try a test example.

This is saved in the main scala directory.

```
 class Hello {
   def sayHello(name: String) = s"Hello, $name!"
 }
```

This is saved in the test scala directory.

```
 import org.scalatest.FunSuite

 class HelloTest extends FunSuite {
   test("sayHelloMethodWorks") {
     val hello = new Hello
     assert(hello.sayHello("Scala") == "Hello, Scala!")
   }
 }
```

This test runs fine in the IDE and it shows up as green.  How would I be able to run that same test with just using command prompt / a text editor?

Comment: Are you targeting some specific testing framework? Like `ScalaTest`, `JUnit` or any other?

Comment: Look at scalatest's getting started page

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Typesafe activator. There are many templates to help get you started

run
activator new

choose minimal-scal

It creates a file build.sbt

```
name := """hello-world-app"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

// Change this to another test framework if you prefer
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"

// Uncomment to use Akka
//libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.11"
```

and a scala file

```
package com.example

object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

and a test HelloWorldSpec.scala

```
import org.scalatest._

class HelloSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "Hello" should "have tests" in {
    true should === (true)
  }
}
```

you can run sbt "~test" to continuous run your tests, or

`sbt test`
to run test once

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Scala and SBT!  Excellent choice. :)

If you save that "hello world" example as `hw.scala` then in the same directory you can just run `sbt run` and it will automatically search for this source and run it.

```
> sbt run
[info] Set current project to hw (in build file:/Users/ben/projects/hw/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/ben/projects/hw/}hw...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/ben/projects/hw/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Running Hi
Hi!
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed 04-Jun-2015 21:17:27
>
```

See [this bit](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Hello.html#Create+a+project+directory+with+source+code) in the documentation for more on this.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to make it to this point at least.  How would I make a "test" that would be a scala file where it's stored in the test directory?  E.g.  say my hello world program could say "hi <name>" and I wanted to test multiple cases where <name> was Bob, Jack, Michael etc.  I'll add in an edit to the OP to try to explain what I mean better.

Comment: Great, I see someone has given an answer regarding the testing bit. Enjoy :)